# How to start programming using Ethereum?

Tags: development, ethereum

I'd like to listen opinions of people that have created already their own working contract. What have you read at the beginning and then? What was the most powerful source that helped you understand Ethereum generally and then deeper?

Answer (score 2):

**Full Documentation of Ethereum "Frontier":**

- http://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/

**Discussion Forum:**

- http://forum.ethereum.org